One unread comment shown although there aren't any unread comments. Is it a bug?
There is one unread comment in the global inbox, but if I search for it, I cannot find it, and when clicking on unread comments, I do not find any. This is since 04.06.2024.

I clicked on "Mark all as read" to get rid of it.

Is this is a bug?
PS: I also could not paste any images at the time of asking, but I guess that this was not linked.

Chances are that the notification is from long ago and might have scrolled past the maximum amount of items. Which means that even toggling the notifications to "Unread" won't show it. You have to go to the site-wide inbox which shows all notifications and go through the pages. Go to https://stackexchange.com/ -> go to your profile on the top right -> switch to the inbox tab.

I had the same just now. Opened the inbox, nothing was shown. Reloading the page made the "unread" dot disappear...

@VLAZ Again, there were no unread comments. And I read my unread comments after a few days at the most while the oldest comment is from more than a month ago.

@Cerbrus For me, reloading the page did not fix it. I opened quite a few new windows before I asked this question.

I guess that this was indeed an internet problem in the end. I must have had slow internet (I sat in a train on the countryside), and I could not paste any images. That together seems to hint at an internet problem, be it the speed or a lagging protocol, which might tell why there was the same inbox problem also in newly opened windows since the newly opened page was likely duplicated, loaded from cache.

Could be, the site has a few slow loading gotchas. For example the hamburger menu in the top-right will take you to a very different page if you click it before some kind of script has been able to run to activate the menu. I sometimes get that when my work laptop is doing god knows what that makes the browser crawl.
